# How to compare usernames in python (comparing lists with title case objects)?

Tags: python, list, comparison, lowercase

I have the following code in Python 3.6.0. I am a newbie and have been trying to get this code to work. I don't know how to get python to recognize (and reject) if the user enters the same username with capitals letters; below is the code.

I would appreciate if you can show me how, *please avoid comprehensions*, just show me the full length code: (since `"albert"` is entered in `new_user`, I want the program to reject the user name since it is in the `current_user` in title letters.

```
current_user = ["John","Peter","sam","Albert"]
new_user = ["albert"]

for name in new_user:
    if name.lower() in current_user:
        print ("Sorry Username is taken, please enter a new username")
    else:
        print ("Username accepted")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a situation where comprehensions really shine - however if you want to do it the long way, one option is:

```
current_user = ["John","Peter","sam","Albert"]
new_user = ["albert", "george", "John", "FRED"]

for new in new_user:
    name_ok = True
    for current in current_user:
        if new.lower() == current.lower():
            print ("Sorry {} is taken, please enter a new username".format(new.lower()))
            name_ok = False
            break
    if name_ok:
        print ("Username {} accepted".format(new.lower()))
```